# Почему после выполнения программы выводится None?

Tags: python

Делаю генератор паролей. Сделал в таком виде, но после запуска программы выводится ответ и `None`. Подскажите откуда этот `None`.

```py
# SIMPLE PASSWORD GENERATOR
import string # all possible symbols
import random # random choice
def generatePas(lenght, lowercase, uppercase, numbers, symbols): # function for generate custom password
    if (lowercase == 1 and uppercase == 2 and numbers == 2 and symbols == 2):
        characters = string.ascii_lowercase
        passw = ''.join(random.choice(characters) for _ in range(lenght))
        print(f"Ваш сгенерированный пароль: {passw}")
    elif (lowercase == 1 and uppercase == 1 and numbers == 2 and symbols == 2):
        characters = string.ascii_letters
        passw = ''.join(random.choice(characters) for _ in range(lenght))
        print(f"Ваш сгенерированный пароль: {passw}")
    elif (lowercase == 1 and uppercase == 1 and numbers == 1 and symbols == 2):
        characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
        passw = ''.join(random.choice(characters) for _ in range(lenght))
        print(f"Ваш сгенерированный пароль: {passw}")
    elif (lowercase == 1 and uppercase == 1 and numbers == 1 and symbols == 1):
        characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
        passw = ''.join(random.choice(characters) for _ in range(lenght))
        print(f"Ваш сгенерированный пароль: {passw}")
    elif(lowercase == 2 and uppercase == 2 and numbers == 2 and symbols == 2):
          print("Вы должны выбрать хотя бы один пункт. Из чего делать пароль то?:(")
def inputs(): # just inputs:)
    lenght = int(input("Введите длину пароля: "))
    lowercase = int(input("Добавить буквы нижнего регистра? \n1)Да \n2)Нет \n"))
    uppercase = int(input("Добавить буквы верхнего регистра? \n1)Да \n2)Нет \n"))
    numbers = int(input("Добавить цифры? \n1)Да \n2)Нет \n"))
    symbols = int(input("Добавить символы? \n1)Да \n2)Нет \n"))
    generated_pass = generatePas(lenght, lowercase, uppercase, numbers, symbols)
print(inputs())
```

[image: вывод программы]

Comment: Функция `inputs()` ничего не возвращает — значит она возвращает None, и потом `print` печатает этот возвращённый None

Comment: Точно! Благодарю

Answer (score 2):

Функция inputs() не имеет возвращаемого значения. Поэтому, согласно её определения:

```
def inputs(): # just inputs :)
    lenght = int(input("Введите длину пароля: "))
    lowercase = int(input("Добавить буквы нижнего регистра? \n1)Да \n2)Нет \n"))
    uppercase = int(input("Добавить буквы верхнего регистра? \n1)Да \n2)Нет \n"))
    numbers = int(input("Добавить цифры? \n1)Да \n2)Нет \n"))
    symbols = int(input("Добавить символы? \n1)Да \n2)Нет \n"))
    generated_pass = generatePas(lenght, lowercase, uppercase, numbers, symbols)
```

В последней строке функции вызывается функция `generatePas`,  которая приводит к печати строки сгенерированного пароля. После чего производитится вывод на печать значения следующей строки: `print(inputs())`

Т.е. вы выполнили функцию, но результат функции `None`, так как она ничего не возвращает. Внутри функции input() нет строки возвращаемого значения то есть `return .... (что-либо)`.